# Are the statistics of the previous session sent to the tracker when user reconnects after connection loss?

Tags: utorrent, connection

uTorrent is continuously running in the background in my laptop. I am seeding more than ten torrents in it. I usually use my laptop for short intervals (10 minutes to 45 minutes); I'm keeping it in stand-by mode when it is not running (I'm not shutting it down).

uTorrent updates trackers every 30 minutes. My question is this:
I boot up my laptop. Then use it for 20 minutes. And then put it into stand-by mode. After a long time period, I wake it up from the stand-by mode. Will uTorrent send tracker the information about how much I had uploaded and downloaded in that previous 20 minute session? Or will all my seeding (in that 20 minutes) be unseen by the tracker?

I'm member of a private torrent community, so my uploads being correctly reported to the tracker is important to me. Does uTorrent send tracker the statistics of the previous session when my PC reconnects after a connection loss or wakes up from stand-by mode (I believe that the both have the same effect)?